# Microsoft Dynamics CRM C# Plugin to use Jquery and Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm

Below image shows my Jquery with Ajax code

JQuery and Ajax Code
[image]

Where in the code I'm fetching field values and POSTing it to the URL in JSON format.

I want to achieve the same thing in C# plugin fetching the values from fields i can use query Expression but i need to use AJAX in the C# code how I'll achieve this?

Any help would be Appreciable...

Comment: You should post code as “code” not image..

Answer (score 0):

AJAX - Asynchronous JavaScript And XML - useful to make Async calls to server side from client side using js/jQuery & xml.

Plugin - server side code for extending logic in CRM platform event execution pipeline (ex.create/update). You can make a plugin to run as Asynchronous while registering the steps in Plugin registration tool. You can do `service.RetrieveMultiple` to search & `service.Update` to set the value in Post-operation plugins. In fact pre-create or pre-update Plugins can set the field values by intercepting the pipeline & even before DB transaction, but this is always synchronous.

But in your code, you are searching/retrieving customerid, customercode using user entry in shortname, address & filling up. This can be done in either way - client/server side.

QueryExpression or FetchXML are two CRM native ways to query the data. Broader topic, hence you can search for lot of samples in combination online.